# Vscode terminal message

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, message

I use mac vscode, and try to run the following file. When the error message pops up, the phrases are partially strange and not meaningful. Is there a way to change setting of vscode so that the output of my error message becomes normal again, something like `Parent.class`, `Parent.h` ... instead of `Zn3_Parent...`?

Below is the code I run:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent {
   public :
     virtual int func () = 0;
     virtual ~Parent();

 };


 class Child : public Parent {
     public :

     int data;
     Child (int k) {
        data = k;
      }
    int func() {   // virtual function
       cout<<"Returning square of 10\n";
        return 10*10;
    }

    void Display () {
    cout<<data<<"\n";

 }

 ~ Child() {

    cout<<"Overridden Parents Destructor \n";

 }
};



int main() {
  Child a(10);
 a.Display();
   //cout << "asdf";
   return 1;
 }
```

And the output I get:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__ZN6ParentD2Ev", referenced from:
      __ZN5ChildD1Ev in ccn2pmId.o
  "__ZTI6Parent", referenced from:
      __ZTI5Child in ccn2pmId.o
  "__ZTV6Parent", referenced from:
      __ZN6ParentC2Ev in ccn2pmId.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't want those things like `__ZN6`, `ZTI6`, `ZTV6`.

Comment: Those are "mangled" names for your functions, and the message comes from the linker, not from VS Code. There isn't much you can do about it, except pass the names to a "demangling" tool. The main issue is that you never defined `~Parent`.

Comment: I don't understand why that happens. I don't see these mangled names until recently. Back then, even with the same error, i.e. Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:, I don't see the names being mangled. Is there something that happened to my Macbook pro?